# Linux modules mismatch version

Tags: linux, kernel, raspbian-stretch, debian

I have a very unusual condition, perhaps a partial update or unknown condition.

```
#>uname -a
Linux sip02 4.14.30-v7+ #1102 SMP Mon Mar 26 16:45:49 BST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux

#>uname -r
4.14.30-v7+

#>ls /lib/modules/`uname -r`/
/bin/ls: cannot access '/lib/modules/4.14.30-v7+/': No such file or directory

#>depmod
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.14.30-v7+: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory

#>/bin/ls -shal /lib/modules/
total 16K
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K Apr 26 02:31 .
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 16 root root 4.0K Mar 25 18:32 ..
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Apr 26 02:31 4.14.34+
4.0K drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Apr 26 02:31 4.14.34-v7+
```

**uname** reports `4.14.30-v7+` but available modules are for `4.14.34-v7+`.

How can I synchronize/update 'uname'? Who is telling the truth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation you described may be the result of a failed or incomplete upgrade.

However your solution is likely to cause other problems

> "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911
>   Even the [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) documentation now warns "Even on Raspbian you should only use this with a good reason. This gets you the latest bleeding edge kernel/firmware."

`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel`
will put it back to the latest supported kernel/bootcode.

PS The current supported kernel is 4.14.34

PPS The recommended kernel/bootcode upgrade also cleans up the modules, and does not leave a trail of obsolete modules like rpi-update

Answer (score 4):

Stefan's problem could be a bit like mine.

I installed Raspbian Stretch on an SD card but then did that thing of putting the root file system on USB and changing `/boot/cmdline.txt` to point to it.

What happened with me it seems is that the `/boot` filesystem it was looking at (`/boot` in the rootfs on the USB) was different to the real `/boot` on the SD.

I mounted `/dev/mmcblk0p1` on `/boot`, reran those bootloader/kernel reinstalls and then everything matched up (`umame -r` and `/lib/modules`).

If you haven't done the USB thing then this wont help ...

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that might be an interesting hint. My root system is not on another USB-device, but my */boot/cmdline.txt* is also modified, as I am having a fulldisc-encryption on my system.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - the kernel was behind the /lib/modules revision:

```
# openhabian@openHABianPi:~$ uname -r
4.14.79-v7+
# openhabian@openHABianPi:~$ ls /lib/modules
4.14.98+  4.14.98-v7+
```

The recommended upgrade listed above solved this and updated my kernel to 4.14.98-v7+

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem (even with the same versions like you) but the "sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel"-solution did not work for me. I also had no error messages and returncode 0 when performing the upgrade...

Comment: The proffered solution also didn't work by itself for me, but I found that once I rebooted the result returned by uname -r and /lib/modules synced up again.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same issue - also the "--reinstall" did not work for me.
At a certain point it came to my mind that I use an internal SD card to boot into my system, which completely resides on an SSD (including an own /boot, which is mounted).

So just in case anyone has this configuration (separate SD card for booting), please make sure to first boot the correct partition into /boot (e.g. /dev/mmcblk0p1) before trying "apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel".

It worked for me.

Comment: What do you mean with "*please make sure to first boot the correct partition into /boot (e.g. /dev/mmcblk0p1)*"? How should I make it sure?